# Using Laravel 5.4 in PhpStorm

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, laravel-5.4, phpstorm-2017.1

Am trying to configure my PhpStorm to use Laravel 5.4 but don't know how to go about it. I have composer installed globally. And this are the steps I have already taken.

> 1.Go to Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Composer
>       Set the composer.phar path to C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin\composer.phar

but am unable to locate the PATH to COMPOSER.JSON.

Who can give me the steps to configuring Laravel in PhpStorm.

Am using XAMPP

Comment: Did you install the composer?

Comment: The `composer.json` file is inside your Laravel project.

Comment: Which environment do you use? Vagrant, Docker or XAMP/MAMP etc.

Comment: Composer knows the PHP path?

Comment: @kuru yeah I did

Comment: @ well am new to laravel but I think a composer.json file should also come with the composer

Comment: @giacomo there is no php path in phpstorm-2017.1

Comment: I don't mean PHPStorm, I mean composer. Composer has to know the PHP path. You should add PHP path to your system path.

Comment: `composer.json` comes with the actual project -- it should be in the root folder of your project.

Comment: Here are some official links: 1) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Composer+Support+in+PhpStorm 2) https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall composer and check that the PHP path is correct, if you run composer in the terminal you should see this do something, if not it is not installed correctly, similarly if you run php -v this will show the PHP version.

In your Laravel directory there should be a composer.json file, if not run composer init to create one